# How can I securely call a web service (.asmx) which is used for internal purposes from AJAX in a ASP.Net Web Forms application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, stateless

How would you act in this scenario?:

I have a website which does INTERNAL and STATELESS actions using Ajax calls, (Something like PageMethods or WebMethods in an asmx file), which are part of the website and do not depend on ANY user state. nor authentication.

The function is crucial for the internal use of the site, but because it is stateless and written in Javascript, it can be visible and usable for anyone who wants to do any harm, simply viewing the source of the page.

My question is: How could I secure this action, without using any state at all? Also I CANNOT deny\block any access to external users/domains in the Web.Config because I have other web services that use tokens on the same site.

Please help me understand how do sites allow inserting\updating data into their databases using AJAX without letting the whole world use those functions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by secure in this scenario without any security measures?

Comment: I mean that I want to use AJAX as a complementary internal functionality for my site, like server-side functionality, but because of UI constrains, I must use AJAX calls to execute certain functionality. But I'd like this behavior to be transparent, invisible and unreachable for external use.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. Only way minimum is to sanitize inputs you receive in webmethod if you stick to stateless. One more way is to pass CSRF token to page and use it as one of the input criteria for webmethod.

Comment: I understand your answer and after reading a lot of articles and posts I tend to agree with you.
But I know there are sites that use AJAX for their internal functionality and do not use statefull calls, like for example, when you register to a site, or when you enter a page and want to increase a view counter. Those are stateless actions used in AJAX to change the database from the client.

Comment: Pass CSRF token to page and use it as one of the input criteria for webmethod. Also, set some expiry to this token which is optimized value.

Comment: Amit could you post an example of a CSRF token scenario or workflow? Also, How do I create this token and how do I validate it? Who creates the token and who validates it?

Comment: Let me ask you one question. Suppose you have achieved what you want then how you will trace unique visits? By IP from which request came right? So my next solution will be .. push unique id to page as CSRF token in hidden field and in header also. First valiation is to match header and webmethod input criteria then second will be hash of client ip + CSRF token.

Comment: Here is some example but in MVC and Web API.... but logic remains same. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks  and http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=890

Comment: I cannot know the source IP. I can check the Origin and Referer headers but they can be altered easily.

Thanks for the links. I will check them up and update! Thank you!

Comment: I looked up the links. I didn't understand how they work.
They all rely on some sort of authentication, even if it is basic.
In my case there is no authentication at all. I am really confused